# IE7 shadow-filter + absolute positioned div outside parent content hidden

Tags: css, internet-explorer-7

[Here's an example...](http://fiddle.jshell.net/aBsuw/show/)

This only happens in IE < 8.

All other versions are displaying it correctly.

How to fix this behavior? Any ugly hack? :-)

Comment: Plz show some code. And heres a list of many IE hacks you might find usefull : http://css-tricks.com/how-to-create-an-ie-only-stylesheet/

Comment: i provided a full example... http://fiddle.jshell.net/aBsuw/

Comment: Oops my bad, seems like my brain skipped it lol...

Comment: There's no "easy fix" for this. Remove `filter` from `#foo` and work from there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would move the bar div outside of the foo div, if you're ok with doing that, then set the gradient filters to the margin div and position the #bar div left 175px and top 20px; I think getting this to work in such an old browser would require some javascript hackery, which is probably more effort than it's worth.

Comment: ok thanks. yes, it's possible. i just thought there's a hack for that without modifying the entire html structure just for this one browser...